# Pi Estimator in R

Tags: r

The code below estimates pi in R, now I am trying to find the minimum number of terms N_Min
you would have to include in your estimate of pie to make it accurate to three decimal places.

```
pi_Est<- function(NTerms){
  NTerms = 5 # start with an estimate of just five terms
  pi_Est = 0 # initialise the value of pi to zero
  Sum_i = NA # initialise the summation variable to null
  for(ii in 1:NTerms)
  {
    Sum_i[ii] = (-1)^(ii+1)/(2*ii - 1)  # this is the series equation for calculating pi
  }
  Sum_i = 4*Sum_i # multiply by four as required in the formula (see lecture notes)
  
  pi_Est = sum(Sum_i)
  cat('\nThe estimate of pi with terms = ', NTerms ,' is ',pi_Est)
  
}
```

Comment: If you set `NTerms = 5` inside the function, input parameter will be overwritten and you'll always get a result with  `NTerms = 5`. Perhaps define it as default value : `pi_Est <- function(NTerms = 5){...}`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would change some things about your function. Instead of getting it to print out a message, get it to return a value. Otherwise it becomes very difficult to do anything with its output, including testing it for convergence to pi.

Also, no matter what the value of `NTerms` is you feed this function, you are immediately over-writing `NTerms` inside the function.

You could rewrite the function like this:

```r
pi_Est <- function(NTerms) {
  
  pi_Est <- 0 
  Sum_i  <- numeric()
  
  for(ii in seq(NTerms))
  {
    Sum_i[ii] <- (-1)^(ii+1)/(2*ii - 1) 
  }
  
  return(sum(4 * Sum_i))
}
```

And to show it converges to pi, let's test it with 50,000 terms:

```
pi_Est(50000)
#> [1] 3.141573
```

Now, if we want to find the first value of `NTerms` that is correct to 3 decimal places, we are going to need to be able to call this function on a *vector* of `NTerms` - at the moment it is only working on a single number. So let's define the function `f` that vectorizes `pi_Est`:

```r
f <- Vectorize(pi_Est)
```

Now, let's create the estimate for all values of `NTerms` between 1 and 2,000 and store them in a vector:

```
estimates <- f(1:2000)
```

We can see that the values of `estimates` seem to oscillate round and converge to `pi` if we plot the first 100 values:

```r
plot(estimates[1:100], type = 'l')
abline(h = pi)
```

[image]

Our answer is just the first value which, when rounded to three decimal places, is the same as pi rounded to three decimal places:

```r
result <- which(round(estimates, 3) == round(pi, 3))[1]

result
#> [1] 1103
```

And we can check this is correct by feeding 1103 into our original function:

```
pi_Est(result)
#> [1] 3.142499
```

You will see that this gives us 3.142, which is the same as pi rounded to 3 decimal places.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I feel like the Vectorize call could be replaced by using cumsum instead.

Answer (score 1):

`1000` terms are required to make the estimate accurate to within `0.001`:

```
pi_Est1 <- function(n) {
  if (n == 0) return(0)
  neg <- 1/seq(3, 2*n + 1, 4)
  if (n%%2) neg[length(neg)] <- 0
  4*sum(1/seq(1, 2*n, 4) - neg)
}

pi_Est2 <- function(tol) {
  for (i in ceiling(1/tol + 0.5):0) {
    est <- pi_Est1(i)
    if (abs(est - pi) > tol) break
    est1 <- est
  }
  
  list(NTerms = i + 1, Estimate = est1)
}

tol <- 1e-3
pi_Est2(tol)
#> $NTerms
#> [1] 1000
#> 
#> $Estimate
#> [1] 3.140593
tol - abs(pi - pi_Est2(tol)$Estimate)
#> [1] 2.500001e-10
tol - abs(pi - pi_Est1(pi_Est2(tol)$NTerms - 1))
#> [1] -1.00075e-06

Created on 2022-01-31 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can try the code below

```
pi_Est <- function(digits = 3) {
  s <- 0
  ii <- 1
  repeat  {
    s <- s + 4 * (-1)^(ii + 1) / (2 * ii - 1)
    if (round(s, digits) == round(pi, digits)) break
    ii <- ii + 1
  }
  list(est = s, iter = ii)
}
```

and you will see

```
> pi_Est()
$est
[1] 3.142499

$iter
[1] 1103


> pi_Est(5)
$est
[1] 3.141585

$iter
[1] 130658
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single line of code for the calculation?

```
   Pi <- tail(cumsum(4*(1/seq(1,4*50000000,2))*rep(c(1,-1), 50000000)),1)
```